# Align RecyclerView below a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to design a layout that has a title and some text at the top, then a `RecyclerView` of comments below it.  The text can get long so I put it into a `ScrollView`.  The code I have causes the `TextViews` and `RecyclerView` to overlap each other:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/commentlist"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using RelaiveLayout
replace it with LinearLayout and set orientation property to "vertical"

Comment: This also results in only the `TextViews` being displayed and the `RecyclerView` seems to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/commentlist"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This results in only the `TextViews` being displayed and the `RecyclerView` seems to be hidden.

Comment: you need to do android:layout_height="wrap_content" in relative layout, edited my code